# Can some one help me as how to write the correct Xpath to get the different condition prices

Tags: xpath

Can some one help me as how to write the correct Xpath to get the different condition prices from [this site](http://www.targettradeinprogram.com/product/829506/cat/iphones/sub/iphone_5s/sub/iphone_5s_t-mobile/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-white-t-mobile)? 
I want the prices $75.00 and $45.00 but when I use `//*[@id="price"]`, I get :

`Please answer all questions at left to get your price" while in the Sheets.`